# i m trying to convert xlsx to csv but i m getting this exception

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: ]

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:277)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:186)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:189)
    at com.simplecode.excel.XlstoCSV.xls(XlstoCSV.java:26)
    at com.simplecode.excel.XlstoCSV.main(XlstoCSV.java:86)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:501)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:59)

... 5 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2395)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2642)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1579)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildMethod(XmlBeans.java:174)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildNodeMethod(XmlBeans.java:195)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildNodeToCursorMethod(XmlBeans.java:232)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(XmlBeans.java:131)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:39)
```

Comment: As you are new user here, let me tell you, if you get the solution of your problem by any answer here then you should accept that answer to let others know what worked for you. To accept an answer just click on the Right Tick sign on the left side of the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing to include the `javax.xml.stream.jar` file.

[Download from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxxmlstream101jar.htm)

Comment: now i m getting this exceptionException in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: when i converted some kb of xlsx to csv it got converted but when i tried for 3 mb size file it giving this exception

Comment: It would be because whatever you are doing is consuming a lot of memory. You should post your Java code to let us know why this is happening. And may be post as a new question, as this question has been solved and you can accept it.

Comment: Apache POI is memory hungry especially when you are dealing with large volume of records. Try this way http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html. This will even load the file with more than 10MB.

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved using the same Apache POI (- the Java API for Microsoft Documents) version jars just simply add jars of same version
Ex- Respective jars solved conversion from

1. xls-to csv and
2. xlsx-to csv and

Jar List-

1. poi-3.9.jar
2. poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
3. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar
4. xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar